# Create or Update - Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

As there is `firstOrCreate()`
in Laravel Eloquent, I was wondering if there was a function that could either create a record or if it exists, update the current one?

Or would I have to write my own one?

I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation, but it's not the first time, I've found stuff about Eloquent elsewhere than the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find model before updating it, right? You cannot just call `Model::firstOrUpdate($newAttributes)` simply because there is no model in database with such (new) attributes.

I. e. you must know some model's unique attribute, for example, an `id`. After this, you can fetch it and call `update` method with new attributes: `Model::firstOrNew(['id' => $id])->update($newAttributes)`. `$id` here can be `null`, in this case new model will be instantiated (but not saved).

As you can see, this code is pretty short, but of course, you might put it into method if you wish.

Answer (score 4):

You nearly named it. :)

```
$instance = Model::updateOrCreate(['id' => $id], $newAttributes);
```

If `$id` is null then a new instance will be created and saved, else it will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

More straight forward and DRY would it be to add the following method to your BaseModel:

```php
public function write($input, $key = 'id')
{
    // Instantiate new OR existing object
    if (! empty($input[$key]))
        $resource = $this->findOrFail($input[$key]);
    else
        $resource = $this; // Use a clone to prevent overwriting the same object in case of recursion

    // Fill object with user input using Mass Assignment
    $resource->fill($input);

    // Save data to db
    if (! $resource->save())
        App::abort(500, 'Could not save resource');

    return $resource;
}
```

Comment: This is bad to do something http-related in model class